# How to let Java Media Framework mp3Plugin work on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: java, ubuntu, jmf

Hello i need to run my "java mp3Player" on ubuntu, my code uses JMF to play mp3 files! 
Since i coded and tested in windows nothing goes wrong but now that i need my app works on ubuntu i can't install the JMF.
 I used bentokit installer for the JMF but don't know what to do to install the mp3Plugin!
 In other the jmf installer for linux does not have the file sound.jar but other release (windows and solaris) have it! somenone know why?
 Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to install JMF just to be able to play MP3 files.  Instead, add the [mp3plugin.jar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5B9wDXIGw9lRmpSbEUtenljd1k/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-miuzcGB8fsXn2EQh3sVolA) to the application's run-time class-path and Java Sound will be able to load it.  (Yes, `mp3plugin.jar` is part of the JMF, but it is also usable separately.)

Answer (score 0):

Put the jar mp3plugin.jar that you can find in [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html) in JAVA_HOME/lib/ext and run the following command:

```
java com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder
```